# Mysql output is empty/blank

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, debian

I am using debian wheezy, I installed mysql but when I login to mysql using command `mysql -u root -p` and then after typing my password, I don't see any output. According to log file I am successfully logged in however there is no output.

```
150605 20:12:29    40 Connect   root@localhost on 
40 Query    select @@version_comment limit 1
150605 20:12:32    40 Query show databases
```

Here is the output image of terminal when logging in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/COrpl.png

and there is no error in the syslog or daemon.log

```
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0+deb7u1-log) starting as process 24810 ...
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Jun  5 20:06:02  mysqld: 150605 20:06:02  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: 150605 20:06:03 InnoDB: 5.5.43 started; log sequence number 1595695
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: 150605 20:06:03 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: 150605 20:06:03 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: 150605 20:06:03 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: 150605 20:06:03 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: 150605 20:06:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Jun  5 20:06:03  mysqld: Version: '5.5.43-0+deb7u1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24868]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24871]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24871]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24871]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24871]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.43, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24882]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Jun  5 20:06:04  /etc/mysql/debian-start[24887]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
```

Maybe its a bug in Debian, but not sure. any suggestions? How to get it fixed?

Comment: What shell are you using, and with what terminal emulator? What you are seeing looks like what would happen if you are not actually allocating a TTY in the terminal. (same as would happen if you did `ssh user@remotehost mysql -p` without the `ssh -t`)

Comment: @BK435 yes true, there is no output and its just blank.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski bash, I just noticed TTY is '?'

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski   $ tty
not a tty
$ enable tty
bash: enable: tty: not a shell builtin

Comment: @nix What terminal emulator are you using? (xterm, gnome-terminal, etc...) They all would allocate a TTY by default, but you may have some strange situation preventing it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Actually I think there is no terminal emulator by default, I have to type `export TERM=xterm` each time. So. maybe xterm.

Comment: This all points suspiciously to a misconfiguration in your terminal emulator. You didn't specify - are you using XTerm, gnome-terminal, rxvt, a basic system console or other? They are all highly configurable.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I am connecting to it via Mac OSX terminal via SSH. 
      `env | grep TERM

      TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal

      TERM=xterm-256color`

and I did not configure the terminal emulator on the server just installed debian 7 remotely and even if reinstall I still get this error.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. You didn't mention Mac OSX, but it is the OSX client terminal possibly at fault here, _not_ the Debian server.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski hmm, then what should I do now? for my terminal? I am using a default login shell on osx terminal.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So I figured it out, the problem is with my Terminal(Mac OSX) not with the server. But its configurations are the default. here is the .profile file of MAC OSX:


       `MacBook-Pro:~ $ cat ~/.profile

       # MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-11-05_at_22:40:13: adding an          appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
     export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
     # Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with   MacPorts.


    test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh`

Comment: You should post this over at http://superuser.com since it is not a programming question, but rather a software configuration question. Since you have no answers here, you should be able to delete this one and repost at superuser.  Be sure to include _all_ the details we've uncovered so far, including your Terminal.app configuration and your `.profile`. I haven't used MacOS Terminal in several years and wouldn't know where to begin configuring it.